# get entire row with MAX() on several columns

Tags: sqlite, max

first off: thanks for looking; your time is appreciated!

to the point:

SCHEMA:  for myTable

```
nonUniqueID    YEAR    MONTH    DAY    HOUR    numericValue
1              2012    01       01     01      99.9
1              2012    01       01     02      65.2
1              2012    01       01     03      -88
7              2012    02       08     21      9.08
1              2012    01       01     09      99.913
1              2013    01       01     01      99.999999
```

Basically, it's two values `nonUniqueID` and `numericValue` with a granular date.

Now, i need to get the single greatest date in this entire database.  With the data above, the expected result would be:

```
nonUniqueID    YEAR    MONTH    DAY    HOUR    numericValue
1              2013    01       01     01      99.999999
```

Because this is SQLite, i know that i will end up having to use MAX() several times.  The order will have to be MAX(YEAR) then MAX(MONTH) then MAX(DAY) then MAX(HOUR).

Basically, the query would work like this (i just don't know enough about SQL syntax to create the query):

1. Find all records with highest YEAR
2. From this set, find all records with highest MONTH
3. From this set, find all records with highest DAY
4. From this set, find all records with highest HOUR
5. return this record

Here is a SQL that i adapted from another StackExchange question that does not work

```
Select * From ( 
    Select max(YEAR) as Y FROM myTable 

    union 

    Select max(MONTH) as M FROM myTable 

    union 

    Select max(DAY) as D FROM myTable 

    union

    Select max(HOUR) as H FROM myTable 
) myTable;
```

which returns

```
Y
-----
21 
08 
02 
2013
```

Compare this to expected out:

```
nonUniqueID    YEAR    MONTH    DAY    HOUR    numericValue
1              2013    01       01     01      99.999999
```

it returned 4 records instead of the one record with the 4 values.

Can somebody please help me with my query?  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT nonUniqueID ,  YEAR ,  MONTH ,  DAY ,  HOUR ,  numericValue FROM myTable as a
 INNER JOIN (Select max(MONTH) FROM  myTable) as b
 ON a.YEAR = B.YEAR
 INNER JOIN (Select max(DAY) FROM myTable) as c
 ON b.YEAR = c.YEAR
 INNER JOIN (Select max(HOUR) FROM myTable) as d
 ON c.YEAR = d.YEAR
 WHERE a.YEAR = (Select max(YEAR) FROM myTable)
```

It returns 4 values because you use `UNION`
it means that the result are join in one column

**EDIT**

Ive just updated my answer see if that works Im not quite sure to the performance of this query

Comment: Except this returns the MAXIMUM per column regardless of the rest of the column values for a particular record.  If I insert YEAR:2013, MONTH:01, DAY:01, HOUR: 01, i will get back a year of 2013, a month, day and hour of 2 8 and 21 respectively even there is no entry for 2013-02-08 21:00 in the database.  I have updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks!  This got me a lot closer to a working solution.  I have re-evaluated the performance needs (data storage is used far less than data retrieval) and have re-written my data storage queries to take the granular data an convert into one time-stamp that can be easily sorted.  The API i am using gives me the data in a granular format (EG: y=2012, m=08...) and it's far easier to store the data in that form at the expense of queries like my original that i need to do for retrieval.  I'll invest the time in storing the data properly the first time.  Thanks again for your help!